# Is YA as a genre being supplanted?

Tags: marketing, genre

Since Divergent, Hunger Games, and Maze runner have come to a close. I'm wondering if the YA genre is resting.

Am I right about YA ending, and what genre is becoming famous right now in its place?

Comment: I lightly edited this to be more of a marketing question. If you want to further clarify it might help stave off further downvotes or close votes. (I'm guessing someone saw this question as chatty or unclear.)

Comment: What is a YA genre?

Comment: YA isn't a genre, it's a demographic.

Comment: Still no clue what YA stands for.

Comment: @SF Really? It's all anyone in publishing has talked about for a decade. It stands for Young Adult, which basically means 12-25 or so, meaning it is all heaving bosoms and dark thoughts and facile idealism.

Comment: @MarkBaker: "Everyone in publishing in the anglophone countries" isn't "everyone in publishing".

Answer (score 3):

YA isn't a genre, it's an audience (from the story-telling perspective) or a market (from the business perspective).  In that regard, it would surprise a great many of us if it were supplanted, ever.

It is certainly true that the YA market is presently occupied with a few big-name works, but it did not come into existence with these works and it won't be going away when they are concluded.

The YA audience/market will be around until kids stop being born, and as long as they're around there will be someone producing (with the hope of selling) works intended for their consumption.

Answer (score 2):

YA is treated as a genre. It is used in both publishing and libraries. It is books that are intended for a youngish audience. There is violence, there is often sex not quite as sanitized as cozy mysteries are but usually less than urban fantasy.

Yes, a few big names do tend to dominate, but there are many more titles and authors in that genre. And like all genres there is a wave effect. You get a lot of books in it for a while, and then the market sort of gets saturated and the number of new titles falls off. Then it comes up again. Cyclical business cycle. Not unexpected, nor new. Currently Sci/Fi which had a major down turn the last few years is heating up again with more new titles and authors. Which I notice a lot of cross over authors from other genre's mainly mystery putting out sci/fi titles.Just wait it out if you want more YA.